# Import Error in Android

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, import

I would like to know why is the android sentence is red in colour. I am quite new and I am trying to do map view for my android. I am following a tutorial in youtube.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGO2u.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add in **Build.Gradle(app)**

```
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
```